# Quartz, rectangle not displaying

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I've written the following code in my loadView method.

```
    //draw grid lines
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat color[4] = {.5,0.5,1.0,1.0};
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, color);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100.0, 200.0, 50.0, 50.0);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

In my app I've added some UIButtons and UILabels to a UIView. I want to draw a rectangle around the UILabels.

I've NSLogged either side of the code and get the following runtime output errors between the two logs.

```
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0

<Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0

<Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

etc.

How do I ensure I get a valid context? I assumed calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are drawing, there is no current graphics context.

There will be a context if:

- You are in a drawRect method
- You have created a local off-screen context using `UIGraphicsContextBeginImageContextWithOptions()` or similar. In this case you usually then extract your drawing into a UIImage object for use later.

Answer (score 3):

Quartz (CoreGraphics) code should be done in the `drawRect:` method of `UIView`.

Comment: Ok, I've placed the code in a drawRect:(CGRect) method in my ViewController which is a subclass of UIView. The code in the drawRect is invoked by these two lines CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100.0, 200.0, 50.0, 50.0); It has removed the errors but still no sign of the graphics. 
    [self.view drawRect:rect]; in the loadView method.

Comment: You don't call, `drawRect:`, iOS will do it for you when appropriate. Also are your sure that your ViewController is a subclass of UIView, not UIViewController?